# How to draw Roger's Diffusion of Innovations Curve in Tikz figures Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the Rogers Diffusion of Innovations Curve in Tikz figures Latex. I am a beginner in Tikz and not sure where to start. It is the curve on the right and shown here.[image]

Comment: Which of these two curves is "on the right"?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach using `luamplib` to include some [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) code.  Compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\mplibnumbersystem{double}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    vardef exp(expr x) = mexp(256x) enddef; % hide MP's version of exp

    vardef normal_cdf(expr x) = 
        numeric sum, value;
        sum = value = x;
        for i=1 upto infinity:
           value := value * x * x / (2i+1);
           exitif abs(value)<eps;
           sum := sum + value;
        endfor
        1/2+(sum/2.50662827463)*exp(-1/2x*x)
    enddef;

    vardef normal_pdf(expr x) = 
        exp(-1/2x*x)/2.50662827463  % \sqrt(2\pi) \simeq 2.50663 
    enddef;

    path cdf_curve, pdf_curve;

    % horizontal and vertical units
    numeric u,v;
    u = 16mm; v = 16mm;

    numeric s, r; r=3; s=1/64;
    cdf_curve = ((-r,normal_cdf(-r)) for t=s-r step s until r: -- (t,normal_cdf(t)) endfor) xscaled u yscaled 4v;
    pdf_curve = ((-r,normal_pdf(-r)) for t=s-r step s until r: -- (t,normal_pdf(t)) endfor) xscaled u yscaled 5v;

    path xx;
    xx = (left--right) scaled (r*u);

    z1 = cdf_curve intersectionpoint (xx shifted (0,4v * 0.025)); % 2.5%
    z2 = cdf_curve intersectionpoint (xx shifted (0,4v * 0.160)); % 16%

    drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1/4 withcolor 1/2 white);

    draw ( x1,-2) -- ( x1,4v) cutafter pdf_curve;
    draw ( x2,-2) -- ( x2,4v) cutafter pdf_curve;
    draw (  0,-2) -- (  0,4v) cutafter pdf_curve; % cheating
    draw (-x2,-2) -- (-x2,4v) cutafter pdf_curve; % because centred on 0

    % x-axis
    draw xx shifted 2 down;

    % y-scale
    draw (origin -- up scaled 4v) shifted (3u+4,0);
    for y=0 step 25 until 100:
       draw (3u+4,y/100*4v) -- (3u+6,y/100*4v);
       label.rt(decimal y,     (3u+6,y/100*4v));
    endfor

    drawoptions();

    draw cdf_curve withcolor red + 1/2green;
    draw pdf_curve withcolor 2/3 blue;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- I've assumed the curves are supposed to be the normal PDF and CDF but the OP does not really make this explicit.
- You have to cheat to get the curves to meet in the middle like that.  Notice that I've exaggerated the vertical scale of the PDF by 25%.
- I've used the double-precision number system to avoid some turbulence in calculating the PDF for values outside the band -3 < x < 3.
- If you want flatter ends to the curves, set `r` to a larger value (but the PDF is essentially zero outside the range -4 < r < 4).
- The constant 2.50662827463 is `\sqrt{2\pi}`.
- The remaining labels are left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 6):

This should give you a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=right,
    axis line style={-},
    tickwidth=0pt,
    domain=-3:3,
    xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1},
    xticklabels={
      Innovators 2.5\%,
      Early Adopters 13.5\%,
      Early Najority 34\%,
      Late Najority 34\%,
      Laggards 16\%,
    },
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    ylabel={Market share \%},
    ytick={0,25,50,75,100},
    ymin=0, ymax=110,
    samples=51, smooth, no markers,
    ]

    \addplot+[blue,very thick] {50*exp(-.5*x^2)};

    \addplot+[orange,very thick] {100 / (1 + exp(-2*x))};

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-3,...,1} {
      \draw[help lines] (axis cs:#1,{50*exp(-.5*(#1)^2)}) -- (axis cs:#1,0);
    }

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will draw the Logistics function with the parameter k, as well as the first two labels. For a complete answer, the equation of the blue curve and the position of the vertical lines would be necessary.

```
\tiny
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\k{5}
        \draw[yellow] [domain=0:1, scale=10] plot (\x,{1/(1+exp(-\k*(2*\x-1))});
        \draw node[anchor=north west, text width=2cm] {Innovators \\ 2.5\%} (0,0) -- node[anchor=north west, text width=2cm] {Early Adopters \\ 13.5\%}(2.7,0) -- (10,0) node[anchor=west] {0} -- (10,2.5)  node[anchor=west] {25} -- (10,5)  node[anchor=west] {50} -- (10,7.5)  node[anchor=west] {75} -- (10,10) node[anchor=west] {100};
        \node[rotate=-90, anchor = south, yshift=.75cm] at (10,5) {Market Share \%};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It's not really clear from the OP but I think the curve that looks like the logit is really supposed to the the normal CDF...