# Adjusting TikZ Figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, graphs

I use following script (see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345179/how-to-draw-rogers-diffusion-of-innovations-curve-in-tikz-figures-latex)) below, to draw this figure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=14cm,
    height=7cm,
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=right,
    axis line style={-},
    tickwidth=2pt,
    domain=-3:3,
    xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1},
    xticklabels={
      Innovators 2.5\%,
      Early Adopters 13.5\%,
      Early Majority 34\%,
      Late Majority 34\%,
      Laggards 16\%,
    },
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    ylabel={Market share \%},
    ytick={0,25,50,75,100},
    ymin=0, ymax=110,
    samples=51, smooth, no markers,
    ]

    \addplot+[blue,very thick] {50*exp(-.5*x^2)};

    \addplot+[red,very thick] {100 / (1 + exp(-2*x))};

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-3,...,1} {
      \draw[help lines] (axis cs:#1,{50*exp(-.5*(#1)^2)}) -- (axis cs:#1,0);
    }

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried to put a line-break to the x-axis descriptions:

```
xticklabels={
      Innovators \\ 2.5\%,
      Early Adopters \\ 13.5\%,
      Early Majority \\ 34\%,
      Late Majority \\ 34\%,
      Laggards \\ 16\%,
    },
```

However, this didn't change the plot. Secondly, I also like to add a semi-transparent box with a description behind the graph.

[image]

Questions:

1. How can I add a line break, so that the percentage numbers are in a
   new line?
2. How can I add a description box, as described?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Define `text width` for the `xtick label`  to solve the first problem.

```
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east,text width=3cm,align=right},
```

The `fill` command along with a `node` to put text can solve the second issue. something like this:

```
\fill[gray,opacity=0.5] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:1,100);
\node[above] at (axis cs:0.5,100){some text};
```

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=14cm,
    height=7cm,
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=right,
    axis line style={-},
    tickwidth=2pt,
    domain=-3:3,
    xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1},
    xticklabels={
      Innovators\\2.5\%,
      Early Adopters\\ 13.5\%,
      Early Majority\\ 34\%,
      Late Majority\\ 34\%,
      Laggards\\ 16\%,
    },
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east,text width=3cm,align=right},
    ylabel={Market share \%},
    ytick={0,25,50,75,100},
    ymin=0, ymax=110,
    samples=51, smooth, no markers,
    ]

    \addplot+[blue,very thick] {50*exp(-.5*x^2)};

    \addplot+[red,very thick] {100 / (1 + exp(-2*x))};
    \fill[gray,opacity=0.5] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:1,100);
     \node[above] at (axis cs:0.5,100){some text};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-3,...,1} {
      \draw[help lines] (axis cs:#1,{50*exp(-.5*(#1)^2)}) -- (axis cs:#1,0);
    }


  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### EDIT

Another way to solve first issue is to set `minimum size`. Since OP wants the text to be aligned in center, `align=center` is used.

```
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor= north east,minimum size = 1cm,align=center},
```

The output corresponding to this line:

[image]

Comment: Is there maybe a better solution to `x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east,text width=3cm,align=right},`? Because I like to align both elements centrally

Comment: @Christopher both elements means? first and second line in `x tick label` ?

Comment: Yes, exact. The current version seems to align is right?

Comment: @Christopher `x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east,text width=3cm,align=center},` can do that. You can try `x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east,minimum size=1cm,align=center},` also.

Comment: @Christopher see updated answer also.